# Strange fretwiring on a classical guitar

Tags: classical-guitar, fretboard, microtonality

I've just bought a pre-loved classical guitar, with extra frets! They look like they were not on the original, and are half-way between the 1st and 2nd,  and 3rd and 4th frets.

What would be the point in attaching those extra fretwires, effectively giving quarter tones available there? (But not on frets 1 and 3 - and further up, room would be rather tight). What classical music would expect to use them?

Comment: An image would be nice.

Comment: That makes sense, it sounds like what I said at the end of my first comment. My guess is what I said in my second comment, some music, possibly middle eastern, that has some notes in between 12TET in their scales. Years (decades!)  ago before tunable synths and samplers I played with a middle eastern guy that built a few switches into his keyboard that would take certain notes up or down a quarter tone so he would be able to play his native music. It reminded me of that.

Comment: I commented instead of answering because it is just speculation on my part. I don’t have an answer other than that is where they wanted the microtones. Is it possible for you to get information from the seller?

Comment: I stumbled on this video. The guitar he is holding has partial frets in the same position your guitar does: https://youtu.be/iRsSjh5TTqI?si=ROaK0OIGyKq6Ihp8

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - this does sound like the solution to the mystery. Please write it as the answer! Incredible, and thanks for the homework!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149034/discussion-on-question-by-tim-strange-fretwiring-on-a-classical-guitar); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments a lot - @JohnBelzaguy, sounds like your comment is the core of an answer. If you want to post an answer on microtonal guitars and maybe link to that video, or Tolgahan Çoğulu's other work, then that would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was probably not used for classical music but instead for music that uses some quarter tones or notes that fall in between regular 12TET. A picture would be useful. I believe it was previously established in comments that the extra frets are halfway between frets 2&3 and 4&5.

This instrument was probably used for music that only has quarter tone notes on a few scale degrees and was also only used to play in certain open string keys, thus only two extra frets were added. It was possibly used for some type of Middle Eastern music.

I came across this video where the guitar being played has partial frets in the same position your guitar does: